# converting datetime from character string on insert via- set @sql=' ...'

Tags: sql-server-2005, insert, set

i have a procedure in microsoft sql server 05 who's job is to take a call to it and send it to other databases based on a user id. i can't get a datetime(birthday) sent properly. here's an abbreviated code segment...

```
ALTER procedure   [dbo].[spAddCustomer]  
@ID as integer = 125, @databaseID as integer = 40, @name as varchar = 'd k', @birth_date as datetime = '2011/01/17 08:28:01'  
as  
--get database by @ID of user  
SELECT @DataBaseName=t.DataBaseName  
  FROM [List].[dbo].[users] U 
  inner join tblList t on t.ID=U.[DataBaseID]
  where U.USERID=@ID  
--do insert into appropriate database  
Declare @sql as varchar(8000)  
Set @sql='  
   INSERT INTO ['+@DataBaseName+'].dbo.[customer]  
        (   [Name], [Birth Date]   )  
   value ( '''+@name+''','''+@birth_date+''');  
        '  
print @sql  
exec(@sql)  
update customer set DateProcessed=getDate() where ID=@ID'
```

i've tried using `'''+convert(datetime,@birth_date,120)+'''` it doesn't work.
how do i get this to work right?
thanks for any help you can give!
dave k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i've tried using
>   '''+convert(datetime,@birth_date,120)+''' it doesn't work.

Try this:

```
'''+convert(VarChar(20),@birth_date,120)+'''
```

Basically, you are constructing a string that you execute on a different database.  @birth_date is a date time, so you need to convert it to a string first.

Comment: I almost discredited your answer right away because "the [Birth Date] is of type datetime for the database i'm inserting into, and i can't change that." but decided to test it. it appears to like it. i have to do a little more work now because it's a much larger script then what i present, but i'll be sure to mark you as the answer as soon as i can confirm it works!  thanks!